# Produce random options for multiple choice ques.(MCQ)

Tags: javascript, c#, logic, random

I am trying to create a program which will create a 4 random options for given quetion, out of which one will be correct answer. Suppose the quetion is the addition of two numbers then options should be generated based on the correct answer.

Eg: Suppose the question is 5+3=?, Here correct answer is 8. Now based on this program should generate the options out of which one will be necessarily a valid answer. The options should be generated randomly, each time the quetion is presented to the user.

```
Following are the different probablities for the optins for 5+8:

Probability 1:
a. 5                 b. 8
c. 4                 d. 10

Probability 2:
a. None of the above b. 7
c. 8                 d. 11

Probability 3:
a. 12                b. 9
c. 5                 d. None of the above

Probability 4:
a. 7                 b. 5
c. None of the above d. All of the above

Probability 5:
a. 8                 b. 7
c. None of the above d. All of the above

Now if suppose question is of type: 72 is divisible by___?
Then the probabilities can be:

Probability 6:
a. 8                 b. 6
c. None of the above d. All of the above
```

Now I want to generate these options randomly based on above probabilities, moreover the wrong options should be near to original answer.
What will be the best approach to achieve this. I am not axpecting the complete solution but just a approach to this problem.
Any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most important thing is, you should be able to evaluate the given question and generate correct answer programmatically.
2. After getting answer, check whether it is a string or number. If it is number, check whether it is integer or floating number.
3. If the answer is string, you can't really give meaningful wrong options other than changing its character.
4. If you get integer, you can add/subtract [1,5] from the correct answer. You can set a ratio of 0.3 or 0.2 for generating "None of the above". "All of the above" option comes into picture only when you get a list of answers.
5. If you get floating point number as answer, then according to the precision of that number, you can follow step 4. If you get 4.567 as answer, options should be 4.565/4.569/4.566 or so.

I hope the above helps you. But I think, the toughest part is to evaluate answers by reading questions.